# No X11 DISPLAY variable was set, but this program performed an operation which requires it

Tags: testing, cloudbees

I have some tests that recently failed with the following reason: No X11 DISPLAY variable was set, but this program performed an operation which requires it.

Here's the complete stack trace:

```
testGetDialog(simple.marauroa.application.core.IAddApplicationDialogProviderTest)  Time elapsed: 112 sec  <<< ERROR!
java.awt.HeadlessException: 
No X11 DISPLAY variable was set, but this program performed an operation which requires it.
    at java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.checkHeadless(GraphicsEnvironment.java:159)
    at java.awt.Window.<init>(Window.java:431)
    at java.awt.Frame.<init>(Frame.java:403)
    at java.awt.Frame.<init>(Frame.java:368)
    at javax.swing.SwingUtilities$SharedOwnerFrame.<init>(SwingUtilities.java:1733)
    at javax.swing.SwingUtilities.getSharedOwnerFrame(SwingUtilities.java:1810)
    at javax.swing.JDialog.<init>(JDialog.java:253)
    at javax.swing.JDialog.<init>(JDialog.java:187)
    at javax.swing.JDialog.<init>(JDialog.java:135)
    at simple.marauroa.application.core.IAddApplicationDialogProviderTest$IAddApplicationDialogProviderImpl.getDialog(IAddApplicationDialogProviderTest.java:97)
    at simple.marauroa.application.core.IAddApplicationDialogProviderTest.testGetDialog(IAddApplicationDialogProviderTest.java:49)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:45)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:42)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:28)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:30)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:263)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:68)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:47)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:231)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:60)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:222)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:28)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:30)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:300)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:252)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:141)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:112)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray(ReflectionUtils.java:189)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:165)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory.invokeProvider(ProviderFactory.java:85)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:115)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:75)
```

In the mentioned line of code is just this:

```
return new JDialog();
```

I guess is related to the Jenkins environment not having something enabled. How can this get fixed?

I can disable that test, but why should I?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to run your build inside a virtual (headless) graphical environment, using XVNC (or XVFB). See [wiki.cloudbees.com/bin/view/DEV/Testing+GUI+applications](http://wiki.cloudbees.com/bin/view/DEV/Testing+GUI+applications).

---

**Edit 20/01/2016:**

The link above no longer takes you to a page with relevant information. This link shows the page as it was at the time: https://web.archive.org/web/20120717015714/http://wiki.cloudbees.com/bin/view/DEV/Testing+GUI+applications

Comment: That link is now https://documentation.cloudbees.com/docs/dev-at-cloud/CI_Testing_GUI_Applications.html

Answer (score 2):

You might also consider refactoring your code a bit to use a mock service so that tests do not need to load AWT. This will likely make tests faster and more reliable, as well as minimizing the chance that they will fail in novel environments such as a CI server.